# Using mod_deflate gzip compression with mod_expires results in no cache?

Tags: apache, mod-deflate, mod-expires

Is it possible to use mod_deflate and mod_expires at the same time? None of the assets seem to be cached and I suspect it's because the contents have changed due to mod_deflate / gzip compression. The server returns a 200 status rather than a 304. The original ETag no longer matches the compressed ETag... Am I missing something?

As soon as I disable mod_deflate, the assets cache just fine. For sake of transparency, my settings for both are as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 5 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 5 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 5 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 5 minutes"

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 5 minutes"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 5 minutes"

ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 5 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 5 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 5 minutes"
</IfModule>
```

Mod Deflate:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
#Set to gzip all output
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

#exclude the following file types
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|iso|tar|bz2|sit|rar|png|jpg|gif|jpeg|flv|swf|mp3|bin)$ no-gzip dont-vary

#set compression level
DeflateCompressionLevel 9

#Handle browser specific compression requirements
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am experiencing this as well, did you ever find any additional info about it?